# Loop results of Invoke-RestMethod and build commands

Tags: powershell

If Invoke-RestMethod returns a list of objects, how can i loop through them and build commands based on the values?

for example, from

```
$stuff = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Credential $credential
$stuff.appliances
```

I get:

```
name      : CC1237-PRIMARY-A
ip        : 100.64.10.1

name      : CC1237-PRIMARY-B
ip        : 100.64.10.17
```

and for each appliance I want to build and execute the following command where the -Name parameter is the name of the appliance object:

```
$session = New-RDMSession -Name "CC1237-PRIMARY-A" -TemplateID "99d11076-8e4e-468c-ae14-badc08affb54" -Kind "TemplateGroup";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this is pretty easy:

```
foreach($app in $stuff.appliances) {
    $session = New-RDMSession -Name $app.name -TemplateID "99d11076-8e4e-468c-ae14-badc08affb54" -Kind "TemplateGroup";
}
```